# How can I use &#187; in Draftail?

Tags: wagtail

The webpage should  have special characters which are not on the keyboard. &'187; is an excample.

Draftail should not translate & into "&amp;"

Answer (score 1):

You should use the features provided by your browser and OS for inserting special characters. For example, on Chrome on Mac OS, you can right-click and select "Emoji & Symbols".

Draftail is not a programmer-facing tool: it's a tool for writers, and it wouldn't make sense for it to interpret the entered text as HTML code, any more than it would make sense for Google Docs or Microsoft Word to do the same.